# Generics issue with Java

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

Here is my code snippet:

```
Map<String, ? extends Object> data = this.aub.getData();
//... some code ...
data.put("ip_macs", new LinkedList<Object>()); //gets error
```

The error that I get at the marked line is (the message is taken from Eclipse IDE):

> The method put(String, capture#3-of ? extends Object) in the type Map is not applicable for the arguments (String, LinkedList)

Does anyone have any idea why that? As long as `LinkedList` is a subtype of `Object`, I think that error does not have any reason to appear. Where do I misunderstand this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specify the *generics* type as

```
Map<String, Object> data = this.aub.getData();
data.put("ip_macs", new LinkedList<Object>()); // Compiles
```

When you say `Map<String, ? extends Object>` it means a `Map` whose key is of type `String` and the value extends `Object` but its type is *unknown* `?`. Since, the type is not known it's unsafe to insert a `LinkedList` object there.

Basically, the compiler is trying to prevent this:

```
Map<String, String> mapOfStrings = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapOfStrings.add("string", "value");

Map<String, ? extends Object> map = mapOfStrings; // Compiles
map.add("string", 1); // ERROR!
```

If this was allowed, you just circumvented the type safety offered by generics.

Comment: Or concretely: you could have done before: `data = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>();` for instance. Only `Object x = data.get("")` possible.